# How to format a Date from String in Swift 4

Tags: swift, date

I have a "createdAt" date string that I want to format like EEEE, MMM d, yyyy in Swift 4.

```
var createdAt:String = ""
```

And a function that formats a date

```
func getFormattedDate(date: Date, format: String) -> String {
    let dateformat = DateFormatter()
    dateformat.dateFormat = format
    return dateformat.string(from: date)
}
```

I can use this function to correctly format todays date like so:

```
let formatingDate = getFormattedDate(date: Date(), format: "EEEE, MMM d, yyyy")
Text(formatingDate)
```

But how do I make it so it correctly formats my "createdAt" string not just todays date?

Comment: convert your createdAt string to date firstly and pass it to your getFormattedDate

Comment: What is the source for createdAt, what type of value do you get that you want to assign to createdAt?

Comment: You cannot format a empty string to any date. Please add the source format.

Comment: How is this related to Core Data?

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
func getFormattedDate(str:String, format: String) -> String { 
    let dateformat = DateFormatter()
    dateformat.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX") 
    dateformat.dateFormat = "createAtForm"
    let dInpu = dateformat.date(from: str)!
    dateformat.dateFormat = format
    return dateformat.string(from:dInpu)
}
```

---

```
let formatingStr = getFormattedDate(str: createdAt, format: "EEEE, MMM d, yyyy")
```

Comment: what is dInpu ?

Comment: date of createdAt

Comment: good answer sir

Comment: Thanks for the speedy answer! Is this how I use it?

let formatingDate = getFormattedDate(str: createdAt, format: "EEEE, MMM d, yyyy")

Text(formatingDate)

Value of optional type 'Date?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'Date'

Comment: ok re-copy answer and change `createAtForm` to the format of the created at string

Comment: Just tried that but get this error:
Cannot use instance member 'createdAt' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available